# JIRA On-Demand Querying by parent

Tags: jira, ondemand, jql, jira-ondemand

I'm using the On Demand version of Jira. I need a filter that will show me:

All issues within a particular epic
AND all sub tasks of those issues.

So effectively:

- Epic

  - Story 1

    - Sub Task 1
    - Sub Task 2
  - Defect 1
  - Story 2

    - Sub Task 3
    - Sub Task 4
    - Defect 2

Plugins are not an option here as I'm using the OnDemand version. Any suggestions on how I can achieve the above without having to link all sub tasks to the epic?

Comment: I could publish my atlassian-connect addon (which you could install on the on-demand instance) for such filtering. Will do it if this comment gets 10 useful flags (to be sure someone else also needs it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is quite old but since 13 January 2017 Jira Cloud (previously OnDemand) supports a parentEpic:

```
parentEpic = Epic-1
```

this will find the epic itself, with all the stories/tasks in the epic and their sub-tasks, it was previously not possible without installing add-ons.

Answer (score 0):

With JIRA OnDemand, you are severely limited in the kinds of queries you can run. OnDemand and self-hosted actually have same default JQL features, but the self-hosted does allow for a ton of add-ons for JQL.

I've solved this problem personally by first using the [JIRA CLI](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JCLI/JIRA+Command+Line+Interface) to get a dump of all the issues in a project into a local CSV. Then, I use [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.1/) to make tables/CSV that I actually need (i.e. All descendant issues of a parent epic).

Answer (score -1):

I think following query will help you to get expecting result:

```
project = project name AND "Epic Link" = 'epic name'..
```